# Make the map of rivers and lakes of the country

Tags: geography

As I understand,first of all I should to get the country's map and the river's list.
To get country map is simple:

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Belarus"]]]
```

Also I get the list of all world rivers:

```
EntityList["River"]
```

but I can't get the list of rivers in some country(for example, Belarus).  I have tried to use such functions as `GeoEntities`, `EntityList`, etc. But, there are not any results.  Could you help me?  Thank you in advance (and I am sorry for my English:)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You may try the [U.S. Geological Survey database](http://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/atlasftp.html?openChapters=chpwater#chpwater)

Comment: Some river entities in the list contain information as to the countries traversed by that river (e.g. `Entity["River","Dnieper"]["Countries"]` returns `{Entity["Country", "Russia"], Entity["Country", "Belarus"], Entity["Country", "Ukraine"]}` ). You could map `Entity["River", #]["Countries"]&` on the list generated by `EntityList["River"]`, then select those that contain Belarus, but it will be very slow! Alternatively, you might consider using the list of rivers on Wikipedia as a starting point (imported via `WikipediaData["List_of_rivers_of_Belarus"]`), but it will need manual(?) cleaning.

Comment: You can try CTRL+= `rivers in belarus`.

Comment: WolframAlpha["rivers in belarus", {{"Result", 1}, "FormattedData"}, 
 PodStates -> {"Result__More"}]

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!!!But.as it turned out,"mathematica" has not class "Rivers"(concerning Belarus).It has classes "Lakes","Cannals".